# What's the simplest way to project a straight line from lat/lon on a D3.js map?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps

I've added several circles on a D3.js map by plotting them at 0,0 and then using transform to translate the circles to the correct latitude and longitude (contained in the array data):

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator();

g.selectAll(".pin")
  .data(geo)
  .enter().append("circle", ".pin")
  .attr("r", 3)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + projection([d.lng, d.lat]) + ")"
  });
```

The circles work fine, but I also want to add short lines (all between points within the UK) between some of these points, drawing on the same set of coordinates.

I've tried adding lines like below, but don't understand how to add the coordinates:

```
var line = d3.svg.line();

g.selectAll(".lines")
  .data(geo)
  .enter().append("line", ".line")
  .attr("d", line)
  .attr("x1", ?) //Line to go from 51.50, -0.12 to 55.95, -3.18
  .attr("y1", ?)
  .attr("x2", ?)
  .attr("y2", ?);
```

Is there a way of setting both `x1` and `y1`, and `x2` and `y2` at the same time so that I could use the `projection()` function (like I do with the circles)?

Or is there a better way to do this altogether?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/t8i7-gxatzQ)?

Comment: Thanks, I'd read that thread. However I still don't understand how to use `projection([lat,lng])` to give a line its world coordinates. Do I enter `x1`, `y1`, `x2` and `y2` separately and then translate, or somehow use `projection()` on each x and y coordinates when I enter them?

Comment: `projection()` returns an array of x y coordinates. So it would be `.attr("x1", projection([51.50, -0.12])[0]).attr("y1", projection([51.50, -0.12])[1])` etc. However, you're probably better off making that part of the data and then using a line generator.